# FATAL: password authentication failed for user 'xxx' error when migrating to a postgresql db in RDS

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying to migrate to a PostgreSQL db in RDS from Django. The db was set up successfully but when I run python3 manage.py migrate I keep getting the error 'FATAL:  password authentication failed for user'. The user name that it mentions is not the master username from RDS which is the same as my USER in settings. I have a .env file with the USER, ENGINE, PASSWORD etc that is being read correctly apart from the fact that it is not referencing the USER. It is referencing the username I use to log onto the computer which I also used when I set up a superuser in the venv.

I have tried logging out from superuser which did nothing. I also tried deactivating the venv which seemed to solve the authentication issue though obviously none of the modules within the venv uploaded so I got errors from that.
I tried changing the password in RDS but it is still trying to connect using the wrong user. I also tried making a new venv but still got the same error. The NAME in settings is set to postgres.

Has anyone else had this issue?

Comment: try to connect aws rds db with DBeaver. if its work then rds parameters are fine also try first `username = postgres` i ran into this problem and this worked even i created diff name

Comment: AFAIK, the environment variable 'USER' doesn't do anything for PostgreSQL.  The one spelled PGUSER does, depending on your connection library.  If your code is supposed to pulling something out of USER and stuffing it into the connection string, you would need to show us that part.

Comment: I figured this out. The HOST in the env wasn't setup correctly. My mistake. However I've now got an error when I try and migrate 'django.db.utils.InternalError: cannot drop sequence blog_author_id_seq because column id of table blog_author requires it'. I'm not sure what that means or why it's trying to drop it. Sorry, databases aren't my strong point. I appreciate the help.